Como consultar datos determinados por su peso
Estoy realizando una edición de ciertos datos con un error en MySQL, debo revisar los archivos .json que tienen los campos, pero son muchísimos datos con diferentes errores los cuales reconozco por su peso en bytes, por ello para facilitar el trabajo, me pregunto, ¿es posible consultar ciertos datos por el peso que posee el json?
Edit: Quisiera obtener los registros donde la columna respuesta contenga 276 bytes.
El codigo que ingreso es:
SELECT * 
FROM fe_drogassys.mensaje
WHERE enprocesado = 0



no veo cual es el error mencionado

a ver da un ejemplo

ya edite, por favor vean la imagen

Hola. Te pregunta no se entiende. Y falta que agregues el código que produce esos resultados pulsando en [edit]. Pon el código como texto, no una captura de pantalla.

Hola @Belt1k, por favor presiona [edit] y agrega la consulta que devuelve los datos en la imagen y un ejemplo o caso concreto. Ejemplo, "Quisiera obtener los registros donde la columna respuesta contenga más de 1Kb".

El código, los datos de ejemplo y mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

ya hice una mejor edicion, espero sea mas comprensible

Ya la respuesta de Yussef te dice como hacerlo, ¿por qué era necesaria la edición? y ¿por qué no has aceptado dicha respuesta?

LENGTH(str) entrega el "peso" de un string medido en bytes
Ejemplo
select * from ejemplo where LENGTH(respuesta) = 364

Además, cuando tu tabla esté configurada con un conjunto de caractares como latin1 la cantidad de bytes será la misma que la cantidad de caracteres. Esto no sucede si está en utf8mb4 y el string cuenta con caracteres especiales (como acentos), aquí la función LENGTH te dará el peso en bytes pero no coincidirá con la cantidad de caracteres.

Gracias, me sirvio el ejemplo. tenia este code:
SELECT * 
FROM fe_drogassys.mensaje 
WHERE enprocesado = 0 

Eso me devolvia todos los archivos con error, pero solo necesitaba los que tenian cierto error y estos tenian un peso de 276b, asi que use tu ejemplo y quedo asi:
SELECT * 
FROM fe_drogassys.mensaje 
WHERE LENGTH(respuesta) = 276 AND enprocesado = 0 

